# Why union and intersection can be interchanged in this situation?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Let $F$ be a closed subset of $\Bbb R$. We define:
$$X_n=\bigcup_{x\in F}\left(x-\frac{1}{n};x+\frac{1}{n}\right)=\bigcup_{x\in F}B\left(x;\frac{1}{n}\right)$$
Show that:
$$F=\bigcap^{\infty}_{n=1}X_n$$

In the solution, I don't understand this statement:

$$F=\bigcap\bigcup B\left(x;\frac{1}{n}\right)=\bigcup\bigcap B\left(x;\frac{1}{n}\right)$$

My questions are:

1. Why can the union and the intersection be interchanged in this situation?
2. In general, what is the condition of an arbitrary set $X_{i,j}$ so that these 2 operations can be interchanged?, that is:
   $$\bigcap_{i\in A}\bigcup_{j \in B}X_{i,j}=\bigcup_{j \in B}\bigcap_{i\in A}X_{i,j}$$
   (my feeling is that, the property of set $A$ and $B$ is important as well)
3. Intuitively, how can a countable union of open sets result in a closed set?

Comment: 3. An union of open sets (countable or not) is always open, so this can only happen if the union is both open and closed. In $\mathbb R$ this would be the case for $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N} (-n,n)$, for example.

Comment: sorry, for m,n, I just mean they are index. I've changed them a bit to avoid any confusion

Comment: One can easily prove that
$ \bigcap_i \bigcup_j X_{ij} \supseteq \bigcup_j \bigcap_i X_{ij} $
without any further conditions. The other direction is not generally true. In your particular example, the inclusion $ \bigcap_n \bigcup_x B(x,1/n) \subseteq \bigcup_x \bigcap_n B(x,1/n) $ is _equivalent_ to asserting that the original $F$ is closed -- the left-hand side is exactly the closure of $F$, whereas the right-hand side can be seen to be $F$ itself (due to the particular properties of balls in metric spaces).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $y\in\bigcap_{n\ge 1}\bigcup_{x\in F}B\left(x,\frac1n\right)$; then for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ there is an $x_n\in F$ such that $x_n\in B\left(x,\frac1n\right)$. Show that the sequence $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ converges to $x$, and use the fact that $F$ is closed to conclude that $x\in F$. This shows that $\bigcap_{n\ge 1}\bigcup_{x\in F}B\left(x,\frac1n\right)\subseteq F$, and the opposite inclusion is easy, so $\bigcap_{n\ge 1}\bigcup_{x\in F}B\left(x,\frac1n\right)=F$.

Now assume that $y\in\bigcup_{x\in F}\bigcap_{n\ge 1}B\left(x,\frac1n\right)$, so that there is an $x_y\in F$ such that $y\in B\left(x_y,\frac1n\right)$ for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$; this clearly implies that $y=x_y\in F$, so $\bigcup_{x\in F}\bigcap_{n\ge 1}B\left(x,\frac1n\right)\subseteq F$. Once again the opposite inclusion is easy, and we have $\bigcup_{x\in F}\bigcap_{n\ge 1}B\left(x,\frac1n\right)=F$.

Thus,

$$\bigcap_{n\ge 1}\bigcup_{x\in F}B\left(x,\frac1n\right)=F=\bigcup_{x\in F}\bigcap_{n\ge 1}B\left(x,\frac1n\right)\;.$$

It isn’t that the union and intersection are directly equal to each other: it’s that each of them is equal to $F$, and hence they must be equal to each other.

Comment: Ah now I see. Your last sentence helps me clarify everything!

Comment: @SiXUlm: Glad it helped!

Comment: Btw, could you help me answer question 2?

Comment: @SiXUlm: We always have $$\bigcap_{i\in A}\bigcup_{j \in B}X_{i,j}\supseteq\bigcup_{j \in B}\bigcap_{i\in A}X_{i,j}\;;$$ the reverse inclusion depends on the sets $X_{i,j}$, and I’m not at all sure that there is any simple characterization of when it holds.